# LogStash issue : FFI not available: null

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, ffi, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to start logstash but i got an issue please check the log trace :

```
[FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (LoadError) Could not load FFI Provider: (NotImplementedError) FFI not available: null
 See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4583
org.jruby.exceptions.LoadError: (LoadError) Could not load FFI Provider: (NotImplementedError) FFI not available: null
 See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4583
    at org.jruby.ext.jruby.JRubyUtilLibrary.load_ext(org/jruby/ext/jruby/JRubyUtilLibrary.java:216) ~[jruby.jar:?]
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5-java/lib/ffi.rb:11) ~[?:?]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017) ~[jruby.jar:?]
    at RUBY.<module:LibC>(/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/prctl.rb:19) ~[?:?]
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/prctl.rb:18) ~[?:?]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017) ~[jruby.jar:?]
    at opt.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.util.set_thread_name(/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util.rb:36) ~[?:?]
    at RUBY.execute(/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:354) ~[?:?]
    at opt.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_6_dot_0.gems.clamp_minus_1_dot_0_dot_1.lib.clamp.command.run(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/clamp-1.0.1/lib/clamp/command.rb:68) ~[?:?]
    at opt.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.runner.run(/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:282) ~[?:?]
    at opt.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_6_dot_0.gems.clamp_minus_1_dot_0_dot_1.lib.clamp.command.run(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/clamp-1.0.1/lib/clamp/command.rb:133) ~[?:?]
    at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:90) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.NotImplementedError: (NotImplementedError) FFI not available: null
```

I was expecting that logstash will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

This error can be due to the `/tmp` folder not being accessible to the user running Logstash. You can either make sure the logstash user has access to that folder or [run Logstash with the following option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/jvm-settings.html#ls-java-opts) and make sure that `java.io.tmpdir` points to a folder that the logstash user can access

```
LS_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/that/logstash/can/access" bin/logstash -f "/path/to/your/configuration"
```

Comment: hi @VAL the user is root that run logstash ?!

Comment: Logstash runs with the same user you're logged into the terminal as. It can run with root using sudo, but it's usually preferable to run as a normal user and make sure that the user has access to the folder(s) you're accessing.